# JOOQ: get difference between two dates in minutes

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I need to find all records with `now() - date > 5 min` date field

tried smth like

```
.and(DSL.timestampDiff(now, TABLE_HISTORY.DATE).gt(DayToSecond.valueOf((1/86400).toDouble())))
```

but ofc unsuccessful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always better to move the column on one side of the equation and constants on the other side. That way, an index placed on the column can apply. Hence:

```sql
date < now() - interval '5 minutes'
```

Or in jOOQ

```java
TABLE_HISTORY.DATE.lt(now.sub(new DayToSecond(0, 0, 5)))
```

Or using Kotlin's operator overloading:

```
TABLE_HISTORY.DATE.lt(now - new DayToSecond(0, 0, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well for me. In kotlin: `TABLE_HISTORY.DATE.lt(DSL.currentTimestamp() - DayToSecond(0, 0, 5)))`

Comment: @E.Big: You're right of course. I added the operator overloaded version to my answer

Comment: It can't use `<` because of return type, I guess?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: `a < b` is translated by Kotlin to `a.compareTo(b) < 0`, which doesn't make sense in a jOOQ context. See: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison